# How to set seperate background color for each comment in php/html?

Tags: php, html, css, database

I have the following php code:

```
<?php 
    $dlikes="SELECT Comment FROM module_feedback_comments WHERE 
     module_id='$module_id'"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$dlikes);
   // output data of each row
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
        echo "" . $row["Comment"]. "</br>";
   }

 ?>
```

The above query fetches all the comments from a DB. Now, i want each comment on the front end to have a separate background color to differentiate them from each other. I have no idea how to write the html / css using the above loop to do so. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ive added in a random colour picker and the html\css for using it:

```
<?php 
    $dlikes="SELECT Comment FROM module_feedback_comments WHERE 
     module_id='$module_id'"; 
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$dlikes);
   // output data of each row
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
        echo "<p style='background-color: ". randCol() ."'>" . $row["Comment"]. "</p>";
   }

    function randCol(){
    return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks !! Amazing help. Highly appreciated.